# Не могу вникнуть в работу простого кода

Tags: java

В двух словах, проблема в простом (относительно наверно) — есть некий класс `Central` в котором:

- Объявляем и инициализируем пару-тройку объектов другого класса `Production`.
- Объявляем массив типа `Production`, в который добавляем раннее созданные объекты.
- Объявляем пару массивов, в которых будем хранить данные полей этих объектов.

  ```
  String[] names; // для поля (имя) каждого из объектов
  int[] speeds;   // для поля (скорость) каждого из объектов
  // ну и так далее
  ```

В момент попытки инициализировать эти массивы для хранения, получаю `NullPointerExeption`. Пробовал по разному, но ошибка все равно появляется.

```
for(int i=0;i<prodList.length;i++) {
    names[i]=prodList[i].getProdName();
    speeds[i]=prodList[i].getProdSpeed();

    //ну и в таком ключе дальше
}
```

Так вот, кто может пояснить, по возможности не сложно, что как взаимодействует?

Исходники:

```
package production;

public class Central {

     //String fName, String pName, int fNum, int pNum,int price, double speed
     private Production goldProd = new Production("Gold mine","gold",0,25,1000,5.0);
     private Production ironProd = new Production("Iron mine","iron",0,50,500,2.5);
     private Production stoneProd = new Production("Stone quarry","stone",0,100,200,1.0);
     private Production sandProd = new Production("Sand quarry","sand",0,250,50,0.75);
     private Production woodProd = new Production("Sawmill","wood",0,150,75,1.5);

     private Production[] prodList = new Production[]{goldProd,ironProd,stoneProd,sandProd,woodProd};

     private String[] FactNames;
     private String[] ProdNames;
     private int[] FactNums;
     private int[] PNums;
     private int[] Prices;
     private double[] Speeds;

     public Central(){ begin(); }

     void begin()
     {
         goldProd = new Production("Gold mine","gold",0,25,1000,5.0);
         ironProd = new Production("Iron mine","iron",0,50,500,2.5);
         stoneProd = new Production("Stone quarry","stone",0,100,200,1.0);
         sandProd = new Production("Sand quarry","sand",0,250,50,0.75);
         woodProd = new Production("Sawmill","wood",0,150,75,1.5);


         prodList = new Production[]{goldProd,ironProd,stoneProd,sandProd,woodProd};

         /*
         for(int i=0;i<prodList.length;i++)
         {
             FactNames[i]=prodList[i].getFactName();
             ProdNames[i]=prodList[i].getProdName();
             FactNums[i]=prodList[i].getFactNum();
             PNums[i]=prodList[i].getProdPerC();
             Prices[i]=prodList[i].getPrice();
             Speeds[i]=prodList[i].getProdSpeed();
         } 
         */

         for(Production x:prodList)
         {
             int i=0;
             FactNames[i]=prodList[i].getFactName();
             ProdNames[i]=prodList[i].getProdName();
             FactNums[i]=prodList[i].getFactNum();
             PNums[i]=prodList[i].getProdPerC();
             Prices[i]=prodList[i].getPrice();
             Speeds[i]=prodList[i].getProdSpeed();
             i++;
         }
     }

     public void Info()
     {
         for(int i=0;i<prodList.length;i++)
         {
             System.out.println("тест внедрения");
             System.out.print(FactNames[i]+" "+ProdNames[i]+" "+FactNums[i]+" "+PNums[i]+" "+Prices[i]+" "+Speeds[i]);
             System.out.println("|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|");
         }
     }
}

public class Production {

    private String FactName;
    private String ProdName;
    private int FactNum;
    private int ProdPerC;
    private int Price;
    private double ProdSpeed;

    void setFactName(String name){ FactName = name; }
    void setProdName(String name){ ProdName = name; }
    void setFactNum(int num){ FactNum = num; }
    void setProdPerC(int prod){ ProdPerC = prod; }
    void setPrice(int price){ Price = price; }
    void setProdSpeed(double speed){ ProdSpeed = speed; }

    String getFactName(){ return FactName; }
    String getProdName(){ return ProdName; }
    int getFactNum(){ return FactNum; }
    int getProdPerC() { return ProdPerC; }
    int getPrice(){ return Price; }
    double getProdSpeed() { return ProdSpeed; }

    Production(){ FactName=""; ProdName=""; FactNum=0; ProdPerC=0; ProdSpeed=0; Price=0;}

    Production(String fName, String pName, int fNum, int pNum,int price, double speed)
    { 
        FactName=fName; ProdName=pName; FactNum=fNum; ProdPerC=pNum; Price=price; ProdSpeed=speed;
    }

}
```

```java
package sandbox;
import production.Central;

public class program {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Central c= new Central();
        c.Info();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так вы массивы не инициализируете.

Здесь вы только объявляете массивы:

```
String[] names;
int[] speeds;
```

Для инициализации нужно написать:

```
names = new String[10];
speeds = new int[10];
```

Comment: И то правда, неловко как то получилось, пересмотрел, там местами красиво и нормально переделал, все работает, спасибо